# error: was not declared in this scope with C++

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I am trying to implement a simple protocol for sending emails. Till, now I implemented four commands and a server class that receives all the commands and check whether the commands are in the right order. However, when I am creating an instance of the server class, it shows an error: SMTPServer was not declared in this scope.I don't know what else to do. Any help is appreciated as I can't complete my program without solving this error.

SMTPServer header file:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include "HELO.h"

using namespace std;

#ifndef HELO_H_INCLUDED
#define HELO_H_INCLUDED

class SMTPServer
{
    public: SMTPServer();

    private: string newMessage;
    private: string newRec;
    private: string newSender;
    private: string newData;


    // overload constructor
   // public: SMTPServer(string, string, string, string);

   void SMTPServer:: send(HELO h1);

};

#endif // HELO_H_INCLUDED
```

SMTPServer cpp

```
#include "SMTPServer.h"


SMTPServer::SMTPServer()
{
    newMessage = NULL;
    newRec = NULL;
    newSender = NULL;
    newData = NULL;
};

void SMTPServer:: send(HELO h1)
{

}
```

Main class

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "SMTPServer.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {

    string mes;
    string rec;
    string sen;
    string dat;

    SMTPServer test;

    //cout << endl << "HELO message: " << test.send() << endl;

    return 0;

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Into define of class: `void SMTPServer:: send(HELO h1);` -> `void send(const HELO &h1);`

Comment: My problem is when I create an instance in the main class: 
    SMTPServer test;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks to me like you've reused the include guards from `HELO.h` in `SMTPServer.h`. That is, they should be changed to something like:

```
#ifndef SMTPSERVER_H_INCLUDED
#define SMTPSERVER_H_INCLUDED

...

#endif
```

If you use the same include guards in both, only one of them can ever be included in another file. And in fact, `SMTPServer.h` itself includes `HELO.h`, so instantly makes its own content never get past the preprocessing stage.

If it's not clear yet, just read the top of `SMTPServer.h`:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include "HELO.h"

using namespace std;

#ifndef HELO_H_INCLUDED
```

So we're checking if `HELO_H_INCLUDED` is defined. Since it just included `HELO.h`, and that file presumably defines `HELO_H_INCLUDED`, we'll always say "Yes, it is defined!". We'll never use the content of this `#ifndef`.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I didn't notice that mistake

Answer (score 0):

1. You can initialize string as below:

   ```
   SMTPServer::SMTPServer()
   {
       newMessage = "";
       newRec = "";
       newSender = "";
       newData = "";
   }
   ```
2. Change code below:

   `void SMTPServer:: send(HELO h1);`

   to

   `void send(HELO h1);`
3. Remove Semicolon after:

```
SMTPServer::SMTPServer()
{
    newMessage = NULL;
    newRec = NULL;
    newSender = NULL;
    newData = NULL;
};
```

Comment: Oh didn't see comment ;) btw - how to format number correctly?

Comment: I added this method in the SMTPServer class and it is not accepting the variables 'newMessage', etc.: void OriginalState()
{
    newMessage=false;
    newRec=false;
    newSender=false;
    newData=false;
}